# Leaving comments when Uploading xcode project for Apple store approval

Tags: xcode, comments, appstore-approval

I'll be uploading my Xcode project for approval to the Apple store in a few weeks. I have a lot of comments on there. Should I leave the comments in the xcode project or do they all have to be deleted before sending the xcode project for Apple store approval? If I leave the comments can that be 1 of the possible reasons for rejection?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 2):

It is not needed to remove comments in the code. You will submit a compiled version of your App to the Appstore, not the source code.